# Does ggvisOutput have a click option similar to plotOutput

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Here is some shiny code taken from the [online help](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html) that creates a plot, which you can click on to obtain the `(x, y)` coords.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am interested to know whether it is possible to do this with a `ggvisOutput` object instead of `plotOutput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to identify points by a click and there are at least two possibilities of achieving it with `ggvis`:

- use `handle_click` as in the first example below
- use `add_tooltip` as in the second example

-------------------------------------------------   `handle_click`---------------------------------------------------------

1) In the first example you have to define `reactiveValues` object, for instance, `vals` on the server side.

```
vals <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
```

2) You then add `handle_click` function to ggvis object using pipe operator. `handle_click` contains an anonymous function which takes data and saves it in the object `vals`.

```
handle_click(function(data, ...) {
      vals$data <- data
    })
```

3) Finally you can access the data with `vals$data` and pass it to `*render` functions. `vals$data` contains a data fame which may looks as follows:

```
      wt  mpg
  1 3.19 24.4
```

---

**Full code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

ui <- fluidPage(
  ggvisOutput("ggvis"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  vals <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)  

  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    handle_click(function(data, ...) {
      # print(data) 
      vals$data <- data
    }) %>% 
    bind_shiny("ggvis")

  # Print values saved in the reactiveValues object
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    req(vals$data)
    cat(paste0(names(vals$data), "= ", vals$data, collapse = "\n"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-------------------------------------------------   `add_tooltip`----------------------------------------------------------------

The other possibility is to use tooltip that will apear near the point of interest.

1) First you have to define a function `xy_vals` which will be responsible for what should be shown in the tooltip. (You could define it within `add_tooltip` as an anonymous function as well) The argument `x` contains a data frame.

```
xy_vals <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) 
    return(NULL)

  # show the data in the console
  # print(x) 

  # Define what should be shown in the tooltip
  # paste0(c("wt= ", "mpg= "),  c(x$wt, x$mpg), collapse = "<br />")
  paste0(names(x), "= ", paste0(x), collapse = "<br />")
}
```

2) Then you add `add_tooltip` function `ggvis` object. In this setting the tooltip is shown on hover. You can change it to on "click" but in this case the tooltip is going to be always shown, even if you try to "unclick" it.

```
add_tooltip(html = xy_vals, on = "hover")
```

If you wanted to pass identified points to some `render*` functions you can define `reactiveValues` object, as in the first example, and then within `xy_vals` overwrite it. (reactiveValues had to be defined outside the server)

**Full code:**

```
# Define a function that goes to "add_tooltip"
xy_vals <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) 
    return(NULL)

  # show the values in the console
  # print(x) 

  # Define what should be shown in the tooltip
  # paste0(c("wt= ", "mpg= "),  c(x$wt, x$mpg), collapse = "<br />")
  paste0(names(x), "= ", paste0(x), collapse = "<br />")
}


ui2 <- fluidPage(
  ggvisOutput("ggvis")
)

server2 <- function(input, output, session) {

  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_tooltip(html = xy_vals, on = "hover") %>% # on = "click" # using "click" tooltip doesn't disappear
    bind_shiny("ggvis")
}

shinyApp(ui2, server2)
```